# Increment ROW()-X value as formula is dragged down EX

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which Im trying to drag down, and thus incremenent the following part of the formula "ROW()-X" X being any integer. Im not quite sure how to do it. I understand the concept of locking and unlocking certain cells, but I'm not sure how it could be applied in this scenario.

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$591,SMALL(IF(1=((--($G$2=$A$2:$A$591))*(--(F5=$B$2:$B$591))),ROW($C$2:$C$591)-1,""), **ROW()-4)**),"NOT FOUND")
```

Its the ROW()-4 bit I want to increment as i drag the cell down.

Thanks

Comment: `ROW()` already yields a number that goes up as the formula is dragged down. Maybe `2*ROW()-4`? Alternatively, if 4 is the part that you want to increment, then doing so will cancel out `ROW()`, so maybe you'd be better with a constant.

Comment: Yes, it's the 4 that Im trying to increment as I drag down the formula.Im not very familiar with excel formulas, how would I use the a constant in this situation?

Comment: What you're asking for is `ROW()-ROW()-3`. Except `ROW()-ROW()` cancels out, so you can simply use `-3`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working. An error message is returned saying too few arguments are returned: IFERROR(INDEX( return_range, SMALL(IF( lookup_value = lookup_range , ROW( lookup_range) -MIN(ROW( lookup_range ))+1,""), ROW() - n)),"")

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to increment a certain part of the formula by 4 with each row, then you can use this:

```
= 4*ROW()
```

Of course, this will return 4 in row 1, return 8 in row 2... etc.

You can use whatever offset is necessary, e.g. if you want row 1 to return 1 and row 2 to return 5, etc., you can use this:

```
= 4*ROW()-3
```